# Cannot create story in Intellij for jbehave

Tags: java, intellij-idea, serenity-bdd, jbehave

I am trying to create a project for BDD in which I am using Jbehave and Serenity. However when I try to create a story file I am getting a null pointer error. Please find below the snapshot of the null pointer error and my pom file. I tried googling the issue a lot but could not find a solution.

pom.xml:
`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.1
 

com.bell.nbd.ndex
ndex-location-parser-at
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
ndex-location-parser-at
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.version>2.0.48</serenity.version>
    <serenity.jbehave.version>1.46.0</serenity.jbehave.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-jbehave</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.jbehave.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/AcceptanceTestSuite.java</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Intellij and the issue was resolved.